# How to append records from one complete table into a partly populated differently formatted table?

Tags: ms-access, insert

I have two tables of interest linked in a MS Access 2007 database. The master table called EMPL_MASTER (from which I only have read access, I cannot make changes) updates every time a system administrator adds a new employee. The table which I populate and store some data in is called AllEmployees. The AllEmployees table already has several hundred employee records loaded in, but I need to (automatically) insert new records every time the EMPL_MASTER has new records. The two tables have different column names, as I don't need all of the columns from the master table. This is the query I have tried so far, without success:

```
INSERT INTO AllEmployees ( OPERATOR_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, etc.. )
SELECT DISTINCT EM.OPERATOR_ID, EM.LAST_NAME, EM.FIRST_NAME, EM.MIDDLE_NAME, EM.etc
FROM dbo_TBL_SQL_OHCMS_EMPL_MASTER EM
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AllEmployees 
WHERE (AllEmployees.OPERATOR_ID=EM.OPERATOR_ID));
```

When run, however, this query shows "You are about to append 0 row(s)," although I know that there are employees in the EMPL_MASTER table that do not yet exist in the AllEmployees table.
How can I fix this query?

Comment: What do you see if you run just the `SELECT` statement (i.e. without the `INSERT INTO` clause?

Comment: @MaxVernon I get a "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" if I remove the "INTO".

Comment: No...  I meant this:  `SELECT DISTINCT EM.OPERATOR_ID, EM.LAST_NAME, EM.FIRST_NAME, EM.MIDDLE_NAME, EM.etc
FROM dbo_TBL_SQL_OHCMS_EMPL_MASTER EM
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AllEmployees 
WHERE (AllEmployees.OPERATOR_ID=EM.OPERATOR_ID));`   That will show you rows that would be inserted.  I suspect there will be no rows displayed by that query.

Comment: @MaxVernon Aaah gotcha. No records show up in the select query.

Comment: That would be the reason no rows are being inserted.  Resolve that and try the INSERT again.

Comment: @MaxVernon I'm afraid I haven't been able to figure out a solution for the select query. I've looked at a bunch of examples that all use that format, so I don't know why my select query isn't working.

Comment: No rows being returned by the query indicates there are no missing OPERATOR_IDs in dbo_TBL_SQL_OHCMS_EMPL_MASTER

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16586/discussion-between-pheidlauf-and-max-vernon).